# Casting an object to a generic type without supplying the parameters

Tags: f#

Say I have a code like this

```
let a = new List<int>()
let b = a :> obj :?> List<obj>
```

It throws an exception saying that it can't do it since one is `List<int>` while I'm trying to make it an `List<obj>`.
I understand why that's a problem. It can't just magically create an interface for me that replaces all int types with obj, but what CAN I do here?

I have an object and I know that's it's a List of something. How can I access the elements and just not care about their type?

My concrete example doesn't use Lists so I require a general, not a List specific, solution.

Comment: Can you clarify - do you have a list of some known non-object type (`int` in your example), or do you have an object which you know is a list of some unknown type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of lists you can use `System.Collections.IList` to access elements

```
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic

let x = List<int>()
let y: IList = downcast (x :> obj)
```

This approach can also be generalized: make your generic classes implement non-generic interface:

```
type IT = 
    abstract Value: obj

type T<'a>(a: 'a) = 
    member val Value = a;
    interface IT with
        member this.Value = upcast this.Value
```

If this is not an option (i.e. because you cannot make changes in classes) you can always resort to reflection

```
type T<'a>(a: 'a) = 
    member val Value = a;

type Action = 
    static member Do(a: T<_>) = printfn "%A" a.Value

let v = T(10)
let mi = typeof<Action>.GetMethod("Do").MakeGenericMethod(v.GetType().GetGenericArguments().[0])
mi.Invoke(null, [|v|])
```

Comment: Looks like reflection it is.

Comment: Worked for me in [this PR](https://github.com/dharmaturtle/fsharp-hedgehog-xunit/pull/4/files#diff-7df4306356b8baa0d7aa12c1c56e94c58a834aa94326de590a9385b4a0252762R170), which pattern matches over the types and handles `Async<_>`, `Task<_>`, and `Result<_,_>`. Just in case someone wanted more example code.